# Averaging shapefiles using QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, sar

I am working with the shapefiles from the OSPAR on fishing intensity. I have the shapefiles from 2009 to 2017 I would like to "merge" them in order to obtain a mean value for all the attributes in each polygon for the period 2009-2017. I have already tried the merge option in data management tools but I am not sure if it actually gives me the mean or what does it actually do.

Here is a link to the shapefiles. https://www.ices.dk/sites/pub/Publication%20Reports/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=35169
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use [`Join attributes by location`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?#join-attributes-by-location) and set the corresponding layers for 2009 and 2017 as input. The other settings depend on the data you have.

   Since you have layers from the same source that match exactly, you can make the following settings: check `intersects` and select `Take attributes of the first matching feature only (one-to-one)` (see frist screenshot below).

   Define a prefix that refers to the layer you chose as `Join layer` before. This is to better recognize/distinguish the attributes in the resulting layer: which one represents which year?
2. In the resulting layer, use [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?#using-the-field-calculator) to calculate the mean for the attribute you like, using an expression like: `("totweight" + "2017_totweight" )/2` (see second screenshot).

To do this for a larger amount of layers/attributes, to avoid doing all that manually, you can use batch-mode, [see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/processing/batch_conversion.html?).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will give it a try. If I understand correctly I have to do this with each new year after i join each year right ? Thank you again

Comment: After doing all the process I seem to have lost some squares when I plot the  calculateed mean  of the attricute I am interested on and I compare it to the inicial yearly layers. is that because not all the layers have values for all the polygons? Thank you again

Comment: Yes, you have to do it for each year - however, you can automatize it using batch mode. Why you "lost" some values is difficult to say, I would need to see the very case when it happens. Might have different reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again, it happened more fragrantly in the Senne  and beam databases for all the individual attributes I calculated the mean for5SubSurSAR, SurSAR and FishingH. I have addes a scrrenshot of the map to the initial question, all the green squqres are the one I am missing in the calculated mean.  The map is showing the data for 2017 supperpossed to the  2009-2017 data for the attribute SURfSAR